# Can an Echo Knight fighter with two echoes created by the Legion of One feature move both echoes 30 feet each on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, fighter, echo-knight

Upon reaching 18th level, the [Echo Knight fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EchoKnight) gains the [Legion of One](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#LegionofOne-1810365) feature, whose description says in part (EGtW, p. 184):

> You can use a bonus action to create two echoes with your Manifest Echo feature, and these echoes can coexist. If you try to create a third echo, the previous two echoes are destroyed. Anything you can do from one echo's position can be done from the other's instead.

Can you move both echoes 30 feet each on the same turn? Or is it just a shared 30 feet of movement between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Each echo has all of the attendant features of the Manifest Echo ability.

An echo created with the [Manifest Echo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EchoKnight) feature has the following ability:

> On your turn, you can mentally command the echo to move up to 30 feet in any direction (no action required).

With Legion of One, you create *two* echoes, we will call them **Echo 1** and **Echo 2**.

Since each echo was created with the ability Manifest Echo, each echo has all of the attendant features of the Manifest Echo ability.

Thus, **Echo 1** has this ability:

> On your turn, you can mentally command the echo to move up to 30 feet in any direction (no action required).

And, **Echo 2** has this ability:

> On your turn, you can mentally command the echo to move up to 30 feet in any direction (no action required).

Each echo can move 30 feet on your turn, no action required.

Or to think of it another way: **Legion of One creates two echoes, not one echo in two places.**